# T-Sql Remove Decimal Point From Money Data Type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Given the constraint of only using T-Sql in Sql Server 2005, is there a better way to remove the decimal point from a money datatype than a conversion to a varchar (here implicitly) and then a replace of the decimal point?

Here is what I have currently.

```
SELECT REPLACE(1.23, '.', ''), REPLACE(19.99, '.', '')
```

Which returns the desired 123 and 1999, but I was wondering if there was a better way.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multiply by 100 and then convert to an int.

Answer (score 3):

You should never ever use the money datatype to store monetary values. If you do any calculations you will get truncated results. Run the following to see what I mean

```
DECLARE
@mon1 MONEY,
@mon2 MONEY,
@mon3 MONEY,
@mon4 MONEY,
@num1 DECIMAL(19,4),
@num2 DECIMAL(19,4),
@num3 DECIMAL(19,4),
@num4 DECIMAL(19,4)

SELECT
@mon1 = 100, @mon2 = 339, @mon3 = 10000,
@num1 = 100, @num2 = 339, @num3 = 10000

SET @mon4 = @mon1/@mon2*@mon3
SET @num4 = @num1/@num2*@num3

SELECT @mon4 AS moneyresult,
@num4 AS numericresult
```

Output:
2949.0000    2949.8525

Answer (score 0):

Could you be a little more specific about the use case?  Removing the decimal point from the representation is a little unusual given that you'll lose all information about the scale.  Are you assuming that there will always be two digits?  If so, you could simplify multiply by 100 and then round before converting to a string.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the money data type can have up to 4 digits past the decimal.  Values with more than two digits might not work as expected for either your original solution or the x100 trick.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the magic:

```
DataFormatString="{0:c0}
```

This will remove the decimal places.

Comment: The original constraint was that it could only be in T-Sql.  DataFormatString is a .Net thing.